# Selenium and Angularjs wait until to do some actions

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to test AngularJS application. I'm facing issue that I cannot do any actions on the page until it loads fully. I can put Thread.sleep(), but this is not good solution as I know. There many ways to wait until page will be loaded(I google it), but I think I tried them all and still no luck. In my applications when go to webpage, everything looks loaded(from visual perspective), but I can not do any activities until full page loads(around 1 sec).
Can you guys share your implementation how you did it that is actually works

Thank you

My code:

```
public By ngWait(final By by) {
    return new FluentBy() {
        @Override
        public void beforeFindElement(WebDriver driver) {
            driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript("var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
                    "angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$browser').notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);");
            super.beforeFindElement(driver);
        }

        @Override
        public List<WebElement> findElements(SearchContext context) {
            return by.findElements(context);
        }

        @Override
        public WebElement findElement(SearchContext context) {
            return by.findElement(context);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ngWait(" + by.toString() + ")";
        }
    };
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on [ask]. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried reduced to a [mcve], and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Comment: The state "fully loaded" is subjective, especially when the content is created dynamically. So you first need to define what makes your page fully loaded, then wait for the last created element or for the state of an element.

Comment: @FlorentB., I added picture with what I think I need to wait to fully be able work on App. Do you know how can I wait for this element to be fully loaded? I added code that I tried to do..

Comment: Use this source to implement as well  https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver. This is how I did in my code:`JavascriptExecutor myExecutor = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
        new NgWebDriver(myExecutor).waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();`  But not working anyway

Comment: What I would suggest is to find an element that exists after everything is loaded and wait for that element. Once that element is loaded, then you know the entire page is done and you can start scraping the page, etc.

Comment: @JeffC, Actually all elements looks like loaded on the page. Only left navigation bar slightly moves from center to left and while that bar moves(duraton 1 sec) I can not interact with elements. But If i will try `driver.findBy(xpathOf element inside  that navigation bar).isEnabled` it will return true, so it means Selenium sees that element, but cannot do any actons with that. So I don't know which element to choose to check if it ready to work on. Any thoughts? So I was looking for something to wait for angularJS fully loaded like protractor has

Comment: What happens if you try to interact with an element without waiting? Does it throw `ElementNotFound`? What if you wait for that element using `WebDriverWait`? I don't suppose you can share the page?

Comment: I added picture, may be it helps.. Actually it does not throw `element not found` . When page loads and you hit `key Arrow down` it will return to the first element in the list. If you write in selenium, you expect when hit `Key down` highlighted should be second element not first one. That's why I put `Thread.sleep(1000)`. But I'm looking for efficient way to do it(wait for angular to load fully page). WebdriverWait will not work because element actually is there, but it does not let you do any action on it

Answer (score 4):

I have faced similar situation while writing tests using selenium against angular app. Actually, in angular app the skeleton or view of page loads instantly but it keeps calling `$http` request in background to fetch the data. Once the angular app finishes the `$http` call, it renders the view with response of $http call.So having a classical wait of selenium like `waitUntilPageToBeLoad`, `waitUntilElementToBeClickable` do not work here at all. The other solution is to have `Thread.Sleep()` but as you mentioned that is not an intelligent wait.

So why not have wait method to ensure that `$http` calls are finished in background. You can try below wait method,it worked for me.I Hope it works for you too!

```
    public void untilAngularFinishHttpCalls() {
        final String javaScriptToLoadAngular =
                "var injector = window.angular.element('body').injector();" + 
                "var $http = injector.get('$http');" + 
                "return ($http.pendingRequests.length === 0)";

        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pendingHttpCallsCondition = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(javaScriptToLoadAngular).equals(true);
            }
        };
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); // timeout = 20 secs
        wait.until(pendingHttpCallsCondition);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried your code and I got exception: `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/jqLite/nosel` which points to this line: `return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(javaScriptToLoadAngular).equals(true);` Do you have any thoughts about?

Comment: Did you add any libraries?

Comment: No I have not used any library.

Comment: what version of java? better to give all imports and java version in case these are new to your version of java

Comment: @dimitriscsd says jqLite (Angular's basic jquery version) is not enough to do what that code is trying to do.

Including the full jquery version in your page should solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't post a comment yet so here is my piece of help as an answer.

Following up from the error on the comments on Priyanshu Shekhar's answer, all that means is that jqLite (Angular's basic jquery version) is not enough to do what that code is trying to do.

Including the full jquery version in your page should solve that problem.